# Using Actions able to select element but not able drag element to particular location, because drop functionality is created on hover

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

URL - http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver = new ChromeDriver();   
      driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
         driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");        
             Thread.sleep(5000);

         WebElement itemToBeDragged = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[3]"));
         WebElement whereToBeDragged = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mydropzone']"));

         Thread.sleep(3000);
         Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
         builder.clickAndHold(itemToBeDragged).moveToElement(whereToBeDragged).build();
         Thread.sleep(3000);
         builder.dragAndDrop(itemToBeDragged, whereToBeDragged).perform();
```

I already tried my solutions but none work for me.
for ex.:-

1. https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544
2. [Java - drag and drop not working on selenium 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391272/java-drag-and-drop-not-working-on-selenium-3-8)
3. [Not able to drag and drop element to another element using Selenium-Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788797/not-able-to-drag-and-drop-element-to-another-element-using-selenium-webdriver)
4. [Not able to drag element using Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469971/not-able-to-drag-element-using-actions)

Comment: looks like this page uses HTML5 events... you'll need to execute javascript to create them... see answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604135/why-this-seleniums-drag-and-drop-c-sharp-code-is-not-working-on-chrome/56615037#56615037  For the "todrag" item, you'll need to use a different locator than ID.

Comment: hi @pcalkins 
thanks for the comment, 
i don't think so this will be helpful, reason on my problem element is droppable on hover .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried with most of the suggestions on SO and finally came up with this, I am very surprised cause drag and drop is achievable through a lot of ways but none of them seemed to work on this particular link, The below code seems to work fine ( Tried with all 4 draggables )

Used Robot class here

```
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[3]")).getLocation();
    Point coordinatesa = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydropzone']")).getLocation();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(), coordinates.getY() + 120);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseMove(coordinatesa.getX() + 100, coordinatesa.getY() + 130);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    robot.mouseMove(coordinatesa.getX() + 80, coordinatesa.getY() + 130);
    robot.delay(2000);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: Hi @Wilfred Clement
First Thanks for giving me answer
But i am facing problem you solution is not working properly, when i run test case mouse cursor is selecting  "Drag and Drop Demo for Automation Drag and Drop Items to Drag"   not the actual elements

May be this is the screen resolution issue

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Yup, That should be the case, I cannot think of a workaround at the moment and I left it as is since it was working, Try changing the coordinates. I will check for alternatives

Comment: Can you please share your monitor screen resolution, version of browser and selenium webdriver
so i make same to my side

Comment: Can you please share your monitor screen resolution, version of browser and selenium webdriver so i make same to my side.

Comment: Resolution - 1366x768
Browser - Chrome
Version - Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Driver - ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69

Comment: Thanks for the Answer and Help @Wilfred Clement